# how to execute node script in react proejct?

Tags: reactjs

I have a project created with `create-react-app xxx --template typescript`

I added some helper scripts like "scripts/foo.ts" directory.

When I do `ts-node scripts/foo.ts` it complains with things likes

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
tmp.ts:1:18 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import path from "path";
                   ~~~~~~
tmp.ts:2:16 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import fs from "fs";
```

How do I setup the project so both react and helper scripts works?

Comment: You are trying to use fs module , you need to  do `npm i @types/node`

Comment: @AnkushVerma ```(node:70203) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
/Users/kdong007/Desktop/projects/tapin-monorepo/route-planner/scripts/splitRawOrderByDate.ts:1
import path from "path";
^^^^^^```

Comment: @AnkushVerma i tried switch to `"module": "CommonJS",` but then react itself stopped working